# pandas data frame to_parquet - Don't know how to convert data type: Int64

Tags: pandas, parquet, int64

Does anyone know if the issue in the title has been solved ?
The issue is that pandas needs a column to be of type Int64 (not int64) to handle null values,  but then trying to convert the data frame to a parquet file gets this error:  Don't know how to convert data type: Int64

If not solved, is there a known workaround ?

Dani

Comment: Can you add code that reproduces the problem? Which pyarrow and pandas versions are you using?

Comment: pandas version 0.25, using fastparquet 0.2.1

Comment: Can you try using pyarrow 1.0.1 instead of fastparquet? This should support Int64 columns.